# Can I safely do a factory reset without losing root?

Tags: root-access, 5.0-lollipop, factory-reset, htc-one-m8

Sadly my quesiton isn't that simple. To make sure everyone unerstands I will explain as short but specific as possible:

<sub>Initial: stock state, not rooted, nothing special</sub>

1. I **updated my HTC One M8 to Android 5.0** (Lollipop) and noticed, that it drains my battery waaay faster than before and also lags pretty bad (almost every press of a button).
2. I searched for fixes online but couldn't find anything that may work except for a **factory reset**. Since it's almost impossible to backup all apps including data without root (e.g. titanium backup) I thought I may as well **root my device**, so I'm prepared for future restores (as I found out it's particularly easy to root an htc device, I was relieved <sub>I'm a noob when it comes to rooting</sub>).

   - I then did a factory reset and rooted my HTC One M8, installed SuperSU and all that stuff, you know.
   - It actually ran faster than before the Android 5.0 Update and the battery drain also seemed to be OK.
3. This Monday I woke up to a completely **depleted mobile data usage** (had about 450MB left - all gone over night). I forgot to turn on WiFi as I went to sleep. Below is the data usage of that night. I set everything I can (Play Store Updates and HTC Backups, as far as I know) to WiFi only, because 1GB of monthly mobile data seldom is enough for me.

   - [image: data usage]
   - I contacted HTC Support Chat and that lady told me to go to *Settings -> Apps -> Reset App settings* and restart my phone by pushing *VolumeDown + VolumeUp + Power Button*.  I did that and it seemed like my phone is as slow as before I did the factory reset.
   - I still don't know why the heck my phone used so much mobile data that night. I just hope this won't happen again. If you know *why* or *how to prevent this*, feel free to tell me!

Now I'm here with a rooted HTC One M8 with Android 5.0.1 and the same problems as in the beginning of this nerve-racking process. I searched a lot for solutions of the battery drain after the Lollipop update, but couldn't find anything helpful.

So my question is **Can I perform a factory reset without losing root?** because that's what helped me in the beginning. But of course I would be very happy about solutions addressing the *extreme battery drain and lags* I'm experiencing.

In *Settings -> Power consumption* there (almost) always is **Google Play Services** at the top. I found some solutions on how to keep this from draining my battery all the time, but they include messing with more root apps and I'm not sure if my device will also run faster after doing that.

Comment: Did you look at the screenshot you posted?  The Play Store downloaded app updates.

Comment: @MatthewRead It didn't! Did you read my whole question? I didn't see any notifications of updates, plus I set my Play Store to **not** do updates via mobile data, only via WiFi.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Recoveries like *TWRP* and *Philz Touch* checks for root verification and in the scenario of you losing root after  factory reset, boot into your custom recovery, attempt for a normal reboot and the recovery will offer to root the device. *Take the offer*. Come back to Android and install [SuperSU](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.chainfire.supersu) from Play Store as usual. This worked well with my Android 4.2.1, 4.4.2, COS12 and stock Android 5.1 ROMs.

**Note:** ***do not use the said approach on a ROM running Android Marshmallow***. It may cause boot issues which you might not be able to solve unless you do a clean and full flash of a device specific ROM or manually reverse the steps TWRP used to root the device.

As of now, to root a ROM prefer the [flashable zip for SuperSU stable](http://download.chainfire.eu/supersu-stable) and flash it through your custom recovery. In case of installation issues, refer to [this XDA thread](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1538053).

Related: [I've installed a custom recovery image, but not yet rooted my phone. How can I install SuperSU and subscribe to automatic updates?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/122780/96277)

---

SuperSU app offers to move itself into system partition which would make it a system app and invulnerable to any factory reset. The option is available under its settings as *Install SuperSU into /system*.

(As of now however, for ROMs rooted with [system-less root mode](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=63197935&postcount=2) SuperSU doesn't provide the said option.)

---

About battery drain, per my experience with it in Android 4.2.1, 4.4.2 and 5.0.1 I can recommend [Greenify](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.oasisfeng.greenify) app in **Boost** mode. Boost mode requires Xposed Framework<sup><sup>1</sup></sup> installed.

---

<sup><sup>1</sup></sup>  <sub>Xposed Framework: [Android 4.x](http://repo.xposed.info/module/de.robv.android.xposed.installer), [Android 5.x and 6.x](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=3034811)</sub>

Comment: So by `in the scenario of you losing Root after Factory reset` I understand that I *will* lose Root when performing a factory reset but I can save SuperSu by moving it to /System, correct? But I will have to root it again for sure? I haven't got Xposed to work well on Android 5 yet but I do got Greenify installed. I guess it's "importing apps to the new android" causing the battery drain and hope a factory reset will fix this again.

Comment: Yes, you can save anything by moving it into /System folder, let alone SuperSu. I did it for AFwall+ and one other apk. It is also correct that you'll have to root after reset for sure but (Recoveries like TWRP/Clockworkmod can do such thing just by booting into them) that your custom recovery will not be reverted back to Original is something cannot be assured unless your Current Rom has the feature for it. What I mean is some ROM's like Cyanogenmod has a feature in Developer's Option which allows Custom Recovery to be reverted back in the case of OTA/Reset.

Comment: Even if you do factory reset, you still have to import your apps, otherwise, I don't see any other way other than Greenify. However, are you certain that the battery drain is possibly only because of importing apps?

Comment: Ok, thank you. What is is, that Greenify can do so I *do not* have to import apps? I'm pretty sure it has to do something with that. What else could it be? It only occured after switching to Android 5 and after deleting app settings and restarting by pressing all three buttons (Vol. Up, Vol. Down, Power).

Comment: Looks like I missed certain part in my comment. Let me complete it. `Even if you do factory reset, you still have to import your apps` which may again drain the battery,and `otherwise, I don't see any other way other than Greenify.` to solve drain issue. Apologies for incomplete statement.