# How to clear an Android device without losing root?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, root-access, factory-reset, delete

I am considering selling an Android (KitKat) phone that is rooted.

Normally, when selling a phone, I would recommend performing a factory reset.

Do root privileges typically survive a factory reset?

If not, is there any way to really clear out everything on an Android phone without performing a factory reset?  Or will some data remnants always remain?

Comment: your data is normally stored in the /data partition. root in the /system partition. if you wipe everything except the /system partition using a custom recovery your data should be cleared but still rooted. you have to try that and obviously I don't wanna try it out....

Comment: See [When selling your phone, what steps should be taken to make sure that all personal data has been removed?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/113316) and [Can I safely do a factory reset without losing root?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/100996).

Comment: @Firelord Thanks for the relevant links.  I will look into whether or not root will survive factory reset (I don't think it will in this case, but it could).  Still interested in clearing procedures without factory reset.

Answer (score 2):

Performing a factory reset doesn't make you lose root access, since the root handling app (SuperSU or KingUser or whatever) is installed as a system app and only the `/data` and `/cache` partitions are formatted by a factory reset. The `/system` partition remains unaffected.

Answer (score 0):

Of course this objective does take some time I'm in the same boat I want to try the same thing I haven't found a good answer. So that being the case the alternative means would be to go in and uninstall everything that you put on the phone that relates to your personal information it may take some time but it's a hundred percent guaranteed to work. That's what I did and I kept all the rooted apps with the phone so I can resell it so that the next person can tweak it their own way.