# I've installed a custom recovery image, but not yet rooted my phone. How can I install SuperSU and subscribe to automatic updates?

Tags: rooting, security, recovery-mode, clockworkmod-recovery, application-autoupdate

I own a Samsung smartphone.  I'm running Android 4.1.2 "Jelly Bean".  I've also installed [ClockworkMod Recovery](http://enwp.org/ClockworkMod_Recovery) 6.0.4.5.

Each time I exit ClockworkMod Recovery, it offers to root my phone.  I haven't accepted this offer yet.

Binaries are [not yet available](https://github.com/koush/Superuser/issues/283#issuecomment-135128037) for the currently-maintained fork of Superuser.  So I guess I'll install SuperSU instead.

OK; fine.  So I want to install SuperSU.  I also want to start getting automatic updates — in other words, as new versions of SuperSU are released, I want the Google Play store app to install them automatically.

Please note that I would rather not boot Android up even once with `su` installed but with no `su` GUI installed.  Doing such a thing would be a security risk which I'd rather avoid if possible.

What steps should I take, and in what order?

Comment: Chainfire (Dev of SuperSU) offers flashable zip. Stable build: https://download.chainfire.eu/396/SuperSU/ or Beta Build: https://download.chainfire.eu/740/SuperSU/

Comment: @Firelord: Once I've flashed that Zip file, will I need to do anything more in order to start getting automatic SuperSU updates?

Comment: Once you're done flashing, boot into Android, go into SuperSU's settings and under clean-up choose Reinstall. After that, install the SuperSU app from Play Store. As you know, if the app would be having an update, Play Store would tell you that. There you go.

Comment: @Firelord:  Ah -- intriguing!  SuperSU has a special option to prepare itself for reinstallation from the Play Store.  [(See screenshot.)](http://i.stack.imgur.com/3xgcY.png)  I didn't know this, but now I do.  I wonder if you could please copy and paste your most-recent comment into an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow these steps:

1. Download the flashable ZIP for  SuperSU app into your device. It would have both the APK as well as `su` binary. Choose the [stable](http://download.chainfire.eu/supersu-stable) build .
2. Boot into the custom Recovery → flash the ZIP → Reboot.
3. After the boot animation you would see "Android is upgrading" dialog for few seconds. Once booted to Home screen, launch SuperSU app.
4. Go to **Settings** and scroll down until you see **CLEANUP** section.

   [image: IMG:]
5. Choose **Reinstall**. It would remove SuperSU app from the system but not the `su` binary.
6. Go to Play Store and install SuperSU app. Since the app is now installed from Play Store, you would definitely receive updates to the app as long as they are pushed to Play Store and are compatible with your device.

Done!