# Root Intex Aqua Star 2 16GB, 4.4.2

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, rooting

Tried to root my phone with available softwares both for pc nd mobile. But still no luck.
But some softwares like Aptoid, AVG, Universal Androot says that i have root.
This is the log from Root Checker

> Overall Status: Root access is not properly installed on this device
>
> Feedback Mode: Install Root
>   Issue: Unable to access root user account
>
> Feedback: Step 1) Verify whether superuser app granted root permission 
>   Step 2) Reinstall superuser app, ideally from the custom recovery (TWRP, etc.)
>
> Stage 1 - Superuser App: Installed
>   Installed: SuperSU by Chainfire - version 2.46
>
> Stage 2 - Superuser Binary Files: Installed
>   Standard Location
>   Command: ls -l /system/xbin/su
>   Result:  -rwsr-sr-x root root 87588 2015-07-06 20:09 su
>   Version: null
>   Analysis: Root access IS correctly configured for this file! Executing this file can grant root access! Setuid attribute is present and root user ownership is present.
>
> Standard Location
>   Command: ls -l /system/bin/su
>   Result:  lrwxr-xr-x root shell 2015-07-06 19:12 su -> ../xbin/su
>   Version: null
>   Analysis: File su is a symbolic link pointing to another file: ../xbin/su
>
> Alternative Location
>   Command: ls -l /sbin/su
>   Result:  /sbin/su: Permission denied
>   Analysis: File system permissions restricted and denied access.
>
> Alternative Location
>   Command: ls -l /system/xbin/sudo
>   Result:  /system/xbin/sudo: No such file or directory
>   Analysis: File /system/xbin/sudo does not exist.
>
> Stage 3 - Root User Account: Error
>   Error: stderr: null, stdout: null, exit_value: 1
>
> Optional - ADB Shell User Status
>   Non-Root Shell User
>   Setting stored in /default.prop and configured as: ro.secure=1
>
> Additional - System Environment PATH Status
>   System Environment PATH: /sbin /vendor/bin /system/sbin /system/bin /system/xbin

Someone please help me to root my phone. Googled a lot andand still couldn't find a solution.
Also tried installing Superuser App.
But no luck so far.

Comment: Someone please help me

Comment: How did you root the device at first place? It is important here. Is there a custom Recovery installed in the device? If not, then install it and follow the instructions here: [I've installed a custom recovery image, but not yet rooted my phone. How can I install SuperSU and subscribe to automatic updates?](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/123538)

Comment: Not installed yet. Just tried rooting with kingroot, kingroot, iroot, framaroot etc on both pc and mob. And to install custom recovery we need to root first. And there is no cwm available for my handset also