# SuperSu update binary error

Tags: rooting, updates, root-access, lg, superuser

I have a **lg optimus g pro f240** running on android os version ***4.4.2***. I recently rooted the phone using the software in [This thread](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2699067)

I have installed [SuperSu](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.chainfire.supersu) though each time I try and open it, it tells me *The SU binary needs to be updated. Continue ?*

It prompts me to use CWM, which I have installed, though each time I try and use it SuperSu does nothing and just opens the app.

Each time I click continue, after 30 seconds I get the error message:

*Installation failed!*

*Please reboot and try again.*

I have tried rebooting, though nothing solves the problem.

If the rooting software linked above did not work, how can I test and see if that is true?

Is there any way to update the binary manually(I have tried sideloading SuperSu but an error in tmp/Update happens)

What options are there that could fix this problem?

Comment: Can you remove your SuperSU app and follow step 1-3 of [my answer](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/123538/96277)?

Comment: You can also use normal mode to update.

Answer (score -1):

Heyy tristo
          Its not a fix solution but for try you can download su binary zip file from google 2.76 version and after download move it to sd card from downloaded folder after shut down the phone and come in reboot in recovery mode normal power off and volume up and down key press one time to reboot but setting may be change for your phone so check on google before rebooting after when its done choose recovery mode use volume up key to select then select install zip from sd card use volume down key and press power button then select zip file from sd card at bottom and press power button and then click yes to flashing after done flashing press go to go back and from options reboot the system.after reboot go in supersu error should be going on if not click on continue and normal mode its showing installing binary after some time it will show installation sucess and reboot so reboot now and then open supersu its time error will go surely if not continue process done again and this time don't reboot click on ok and close supersu and open again problem may be solve 
Your qutipie AJ

Comment: Please punctuation and sentences to make your answer readable.